# Using PredicateBuilder to build query searching across multiple columns of Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees, predicatebuilder

I have a list of field names. I am trying to build a predicate to look in the fields to see if they contain the search term. I have gone done the path listed in this [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656600/using-predicatebuilder-is-there-a-way-to-build-a-predicate-off-of-a-variable-len) but do not understand how to do a **Contains** instead of a **NotEqual**.

```
string searchTerm = "Fred";    
foreach (var field in FieldNames)
{
    myPredicate= myPredicate.And(m => m.*field*.Contains(searchTerm));                    
}
```

My code so far:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MultiColumnSearchExpression<T>(string fieldName,string searchValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
    var fieldAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, fieldName);
   //this next line should do a Contains rather then NotEqual but how?
    var body = Expression.NotEqual(fieldAccess, nullValue);

    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    return expr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to call [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

It is a `String` class *instance* method with the following signature

```
public bool Contains(string value)
```

which can be mapped to the following `Expression.Call` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336138(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Expression instance,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

And here is how:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsPredicate<T>(string memberName, string searchValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
    var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberName);
    var body = Expression.Call(
        member,
        "Contains",
        Type.EmptyTypes, // no generic type arguments
        Expression.Constant(searchValue)
    );    
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expression.NotEqual` is the binary operator `!=`. Since your `Contains` call is not a binary operator, there is no direct replacement for this.

Instead, what you need to do is a method call of `Contains`. So you first need to get the `MethodInfo` object for the `string.Contains` function.

It should look like this:

```
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
var body = Expression.Call(fieldAccess, method, Expression.Constant(searchValue));
```